# Hibernate object ID

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to use objects as @Id but Hibernate doesn't seem to convert the object to the corresponding primitive type stated using an AttributeConverter.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ris_exam")
public class Exam {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long examId;
}


public class ExamId  {
  private Long id;
  public ExamId(final Long id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}




@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ExamIdCodeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ExamId, Long> {

  @Override
  public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(ExamId arg0) {
    return arg0.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public ExamId convertToEntityAttribute(Long arg0) {
    return new ExamId(arg0);
  }
}
```

Hibernate does this query when creating the table

```
create table ris_exam (id varbinary(255) identity not null, ...)
```

Comment: What makes you to design it like that?

Comment: in my methods I can use the object ExamId instead of a uninformative and unchecked long type. Also I one day I want to switch from long to something else I don't have to update all my methods parameters but only edit the ExamId and the AttributeConverter objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play around with wrapping of the basic column then you must take into consideration that most likely you will not be able to use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation on your id (the same goes for using the `@EmbeddedId` which is more suitable than the converter in my opinion anyway).

If you need to anyway then in my opinion you could try the `@IdClass` feature but remember that the `ExamId` class would only be used while specifiying the queries / retrieving specific entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ris_exam")
@IdClass(ExamId.class)
public class Exam {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long examId;
}
```

in DAO:

```
ExamId id = new ExamId(1L);
session.get(Exam.class, id);
```

when retrieved, the entities would contain plain long types.

Just an option for you to consider..